# What make # go in different line instead of continuing the line?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop, undefined-behavior

I'm not sure why # go in the wrong line when it supposed to continue after 'u'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LEN 5

int inputNumber() {
    int size;
    printf("Input Size: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    printf("===\nTriangle Size is %d\n===\n",size);
    return size;
}

void printTriangle(int size, char ch[]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if(j<=LEN)
                printf("%c ",ch[j]);
            if(j>LEN)
                printf("# ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    char arr_char[LEN] = {'a','e','i','o','u'};
    int number;
    number = inputNumber();
    printTriangle(number,arr_char);
    return 0;
}
```

I used to ask about this same code before but I want to try using if-else instead of ? :  because I haven't learn that yet in class so I want to know if it's possible using basic thing like if-else.

[image]

Comment: `arr_char` has 5 elements, the last index you are allowed to access is `4`. Your code goes beyond that.

Comment: What I want to make is that if it go beyond the elements in array then print out '#' instead

Comment: Yes, but your code goes beyond the end of the array. You need to fix that.

Comment: Oh Alright. wait a minute Let me fix it.  Edit : saw it now

Comment: There is probably a `\n` character in memory just behind your array. When you print `arr_char[5]` you print it. It could also print smileys or other "random" characters. That's what undefined behaviour does...

Comment: Soooo The problem was that I use <=   instead of <  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior because you are trying to access memory beyond the declared array `arr_char` in this if statement

```
        if(j<=LEN)
            printf("%c ",ch[j]);
```

The valid range of indices for the array is `[0, LEN )`.

You need to rewrite the if statement like

```
        if(j < LEN)
            printf("%c ",ch[j]);
```

As it is seen from the output picture it seems that in the byte just after the array it occurred such a way that there is stored the new line character `'\n'`.

```
a e i o u
a e i o u

a e i o u
 #
```